# Blackberry Spark Android SDK error with bBMEnterprise.Start()

Tags: android, xamarin.android, sdk, blackberry

I'm building an Xamarin Android App in using BlackBerry Spark Communications Services SDK. I have created SDK binding to use in Xamarin project. I have configured my application in sandbox environment using https://developer.blackberry.com/files/bbm-enterprise/documents/guide/html/gettingStarted.html

In application, I have configured the SDK with my Domain and then initialized BBMEnterprise.
When I'm calling Start() function, BBMEnterprise.Instance.Start() method is returning as True But when I'm reading BBMEnterpriseState, it's always returning as FAILED.

Here is the log:-
I/com.bbm.enterprise.ui(22817): Starting BBM Enterprise SDK with app name: com.ruby.bbm.example.quickstart version: 1.11.0.6 using sandbox
...
I/com.bbm.enterprise.ui(22817): **BBMEnterprise client initialized**
...
E/com.rim (22817): [2] **rim::os::checkDefaultLocale(): Cowardly refusing to change LANG=en-US environment variable that is not "C" or "POSIX"**
E/com.rim (22817): [2] [SHUTDOWN] bbmcore 1.11.0.6: Uncaught exception: rim::main::init_error: status=127
I/com.rim (22817): [4] [SHUTDOWN] bbmcore 1.11.0.6: Shutdown complete; exiting pid=22817 with status=127
I/com.bbm.enterprise.ui.servicelayer(22817): BBM Core wrapper onStopped received.
W/com.bbm.enterprise.ui(22817): BBM Core wrapper reporting fatal error: true
I/mono-stdout(22817): **startSuccessful: True**
I/com.bbm.enterprise.ui.servicelayer(22817): **BBM Core wrapper service layer status: disconnected**

Can somebody please help me to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately BlackBerry does not support Xamarin for the SDK. A BBMEnterpriseState of FAILED means an error has occurred. You can try further investigating by calling the below method to get the failure reason:

https://developer.blackberry.com/files/bbm-enterprise/documents/guide/reference/android/com/bbm/sdk/BBMEnterprise.html#getFailureReason--

Comment: Thank you @JeffinWithYa. I tried calling failure reason and it's FATAL error.